# Combining field data on different rows into 1 row

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following:

Part  Code   Note

TC    5      OT218

TC    10     RW

I'd like to be similar to the following:

Part  Note

TC    OT218 RW

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there any expression that you've tried so far?  We'll need a little more effort from you before we can assist you with a specific problem in your efforts.

Comment: I've tried a number of concatenate formulas but can't find one to work.  I've also done some research on join(lookupset) but don't know how to properly format - I always get errors.  Basically it's a product, comment code, and comment.  I have the report filtered to show only comment codes 5 and 10, but I need them on the same line so the quantities do not duplicate (quantities not shown in original post).